# RStudio crashes when reading mzML file, R terminal doesn't

Tags: r, rstudio

I've got a bunch of data in the mass-spec mzML file format. Using the latest version of R (v3.3.2), and the latest daily of RStudio (v1.1.47), reading in an mzML file crashes R in RStudio, but not R in the terminal.

```
library(mzR)
library(msdata)

mzxml <- system.file("threonine/threonine_i2_e35_pH_tree.mzXML",
                     package = "msdata")
aa <- openMSfile(mzxml) # this works

mzml <- system.file("microtofq/MM8.mzML", package = "msdata")

bb <- openMSfile(mzml) # this crashes R, but only in RStudio

sessionInfo()

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] msdata_0.14.0 mzR_2.8.1     Rcpp_0.12.9  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] ProtGenerics_1.6.0  parallel_3.3.2      Biobase_2.34.0     
[4] codetools_0.2-15    BiocGenerics_0.20.0
```

**Update**

Running with `lldb` attached (by the way, make sure to run that as root!), gives the following stacktrace:

```
error: mzR.so 0x010c47ab: DW_TAG_member '_M_local_buf' refers to type 0x0110cd75 which extends beyond the bounds of 0x010c47a3
error: mzR.so 0x00efe9cd: DW_TAG_member '_M_local_buf' refers to type 0x00f369c9 which extends beyond the bounds of 0x00efe9c5
error: mzR.so 0x000000cc: DW_TAG_member '_M_local_buf' refers to type 0x0000a52f which extends beyond the bounds of 0x000000c4
* thread #1: tid = 3799, 0x0000000000da88cd rsession`boost::filesystem::path::filename() const + 189, name = 'rsession', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x83e6de7)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000000da88cd rsession`boost::filesystem::path::filename() const + 189
    frame #1: 0x00007f2b01ed4aaf mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::IO::HandlerMSData::startElement(this=0x00007ffcdab7b9f0, name=<unavailable>, attributes=<unavailable>, position=<unavailable>) + 511 at IO.cpp:2666
    frame #2: 0x00007f2b01fd1593 mzR.so`pwiz::minimxml::SAXParser::(anonymous namespace)::HandlerWrangler::startElement(this=0x00007ffcdab7b5b0, name="mzML", attributes=0x00007ffcdab7b558, position=45) const + 147 at SAXParser.cpp:211
    frame #3: 0x00007f2b01fd2cfa mzR.so`pwiz::minimxml::SAXParser::parse(is=0x00000000066528c0, handler=0x00007ffcdab7b9f0) + 2810 at SAXParser.cpp:531
    frame #4: 0x00007f2b01ec1927 mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::IO::read(is=0x00000000066528c0, msd=0x0000000004acc510, spectrumListFlag=IgnoreSpectrumList) + 3671 at IO.cpp:2766
    frame #5: 0x00007f2b01e5747b mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::Serializer_mzML::Impl::read(this=0x000000000501ff30, is=shared_ptr<std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > > @ 0x00007ffcdab7c8e0, msd=0x0000000004acc510) const + 107 at Serializer_mzML.cpp:223
    frame #6: 0x00007f2b01e57b2a mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::Serializer_mzML::read(this=<unavailable>, is=<unavailable>, msd=<unavailable>) const + 58 at Serializer_mzML.cpp:250
    frame #7: 0x00007f2b01e43964 mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::Reader_mzML::read(this=<unavailable>, filename="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML", head=<unavailable>, result=0x0000000004acc510, runIndex=<unavailable>, config=<unavailable>) const + 948 at DefaultReaderList.cpp:148
    frame #8: 0x00007f2b01e5d855 mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::ReaderList::read(this=0x00000000058e1170, filename="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML", head="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\r\n<mzML xmlns=\"http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml http://psidev.info/files/ms/mzML/xsd/mzML1.1.0.xsd\" version=\"1.1.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n<cvList count=\"2\">\r\n<cv id=\"MS\" fullName=\"Proteomics Standards Initiative Mass Spectrometry Vocabularies\" version=\"2.26.0\" URI=\"http://psidev.cvs.sourceforge.net/*checkout*/psidev/psi/psi-ms/mzML/controlledVocabulary/psi-ms.obo\"/>\r\n<cv id=\"UO\" fullName=", result=0x0000000004acc510, sampleIndex=0, config=0x00007ffcdab7cb10) const + 181 at Reader.cpp:101
    frame #9: 0x00007f2b01eea60f mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::(anonymous namespace)::(filename="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML", msd=0x0000000004acc510, reader=0x00000000058e1170, head="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\r\n<mzML xmlns=\"http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml http://psidev.info/files/ms/mzML/xsd/mzML1.1.0.xsd\" version=\"1.1.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n<cvList count=\"2\">\r\n<cv id=\"MS\" fullName=\"Proteomics Standards Initiative Mass Spectrometry Vocabularies\" version=\"2.26.0\" URI=\"http://psidev.cvs.sourceforge.net/*checkout*/psidev/psi/psi-ms/mzML/controlledVocabulary/psi-ms.obo\"/>\r\n<cv id=\"UO\" fullName=")(const string &const, pwiz::msdata::MSData &const, const pwiz::msdata::Reader &const, const string &const) + 127 at MSDataFile.cpp:61
    frame #10: 0x00007f2b01eec0ba mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::MSDataFile::MSDataFile(this=0x0000000004acc510, filename="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML", reader=<unavailable>, calculateSourceFileChecksum=<unavailable>) + 218 at MSDataFile.cpp:91
    frame #11: 0x00007f2b01ee434a mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::RAMPAdapter::RAMPAdapter(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) [inlined] pwiz::msdata::RAMPAdapter::Impl::Impl(filename="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML", this=0x0000000004acc510) + 5 at RAMPAdapter.cpp:49
    frame #12: 0x00007f2b01ee4345 mzR.so`pwiz::msdata::RAMPAdapter::RAMPAdapter(this=0x00000000050b8110, filename="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML") + 37 at RAMPAdapter.cpp:296
    frame #13: 0x00007f2b01d3df7e mzR.so`rampOpenFile(filename="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML") + 542 at ramp.cpp:284
    frame #14: 0x00007f2b01d3cd15 mzR.so`cRamp::cRamp(this=0x00000000050e4ce0, fileName="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML", declaredScansOnly=<unavailable>) + 149 at cramp.cpp:75
    frame #15: 0x00007f2b01d45af8 mzR.so`RcppRamp::open(this=0x0000000004fd0ec0, fileName="/software/R_libs/R332_bioc34/msdata/microtofq/MM8.mzML", declaredScansOnly=<unavailable>) + 72 at RcppRamp.cpp:23
    frame #16: 0x00007f2b01d5a955 mzR.so`Rcpp::CppMethod2<RcppRamp, void, char const*, bool>::operator(this=0x00000000050c9990, object=0x0000000004fd0ec0, args=<unavailable>)(RcppRamp*, SEXPREC**) + 245 at Module_generated_CppMethod.h:215
    frame #17: 0x00007f2b01d570f0 mzR.so`Rcpp::class_<RcppRamp>::invoke_void(this=<unavailable>, method_xp=<unavailable>, object=0x0000000005cbe020, args=0x00007ffcdab7d2f0, nargs=<unavailable>) + 176 at class.h:212
    frame #18: 0x00007f2b027e3f41 Rcpp.so`CppMethod__invoke_void(args=<unavailable>) + 449 at Module.cpp:200
    frame #19: 0x00007f2b26a6e9b1 libR.so`do_External(call=0x000000000570f208, op=0x000000000333ac20, args=0x0000000005dd50b8, env=0x0000000005dd50f0) + 337 at dotcode.c:548
    frame #20: 0x00007f2b26aa86df libR.so`Rf_eval(e=0x000000000570f208, rho=0x0000000005dd50f0) + 1871 at eval.c:713
    frame #21: 0x00007f2b26aaadf8 libR.so`do_begin(call=0x000000000570f198, op=0x00000000033254d8, args=0x000000000570f358, rho=0x0000000005dd50f0) + 344 at eval.c:1807
    frame #22: 0x00007f2b26aa84d1 libR.so`Rf_eval(e=<unavailable>, rho=0x0000000005dd50f0) + 1345 at eval.c:685
    frame #23: 0x00007f2b26aa9d8d libR.so`Rf_applyClosure(call=<unavailable>, op=<unavailable>, arglist=<unavailable>, rho=<unavailable>, suppliedvars=0x000000000330a1c8) + 1309 at eval.c:1135
    frame #24: 0x00007f2b26aa82ad libR.so`Rf_eval(e=0x00000000062d0ad8, rho=0x000000000595b3e0) + 797 at eval.c:732
    frame #25: 0x00007f2b26aaadf8 libR.so`do_begin(call=0x00000000062d0d08, op=0x00000000033254d8, args=0x00000000062d0b10, rho=0x000000000595b3e0) + 344 at eval.c:1807
    frame #26: 0x00007f2b26aa84d1 libR.so`Rf_eval(e=<unavailable>, rho=0x000000000595b3e0) + 1345 at eval.c:685
    frame #27: 0x00007f2b26aa84d1 libR.so`Rf_eval(e=<unavailable>, rho=0x000000000595b3e0) + 1345 at eval.c:685
    frame #28: 0x00007f2b26aaadf8 libR.so`do_begin(call=0x00000000062d04a0, op=0x00000000033254d8, args=0x00000000062d0e90, rho=0x000000000595b3e0) + 344 at eval.c:1807
    frame #29: 0x00007f2b26aa84d1 libR.so`Rf_eval(e=<unavailable>, rho=0x000000000595b3e0) + 1345 at eval.c:685
    frame #30: 0x00007f2b26aa9d8d libR.so`Rf_applyClosure(call=<unavailable>, op=<unavailable>, arglist=<unavailable>, rho=<unavailable>, suppliedvars=0x000000000330a1c8) + 1309 at eval.c:1135
    frame #31: 0x00007f2b26aa82ad libR.so`Rf_eval(e=0x000000000595a9f0, rho=0x000000000334ff58) + 797 at eval.c:732
    frame #32: 0x00007f2b26aabf66 libR.so`do_set(call=0x000000000595b680, op=0x000000000330c2d8, args=<unavailable>, rho=0x000000000334ff58) + 166 at eval.c:2197
    frame #33: 0x00007f2b26aa84d1 libR.so`Rf_eval(e=<unavailable>, rho=0x000000000334ff58) + 1345 at eval.c:685
    frame #34: 0x00007f2b26acf932 libR.so`Rf_ReplIteration(rho=0x000000000334ff58, savestack=<unavailable>, browselevel=<unavailable>, state=0x00007ffcdab7f020) + 546 at main.c:258
    frame #35: 0x00007f2b26acfca1 libR.so`R_ReplConsole(rho=0x000000000334ff58, savestack=0, browselevel=0) + 129 at main.c:308
    frame #36: 0x00007f2b26acfd58 libR.so`run_Rmainloop + 72 at main.c:1059
    frame #37: 0x0000000000d85dc2 rsession`rstudio::r::session::runEmbeddedR(rstudio::core::FilePath const&, rstudio::core::FilePath const&, bool, bool, SA_TYPE, rstudio::r::session::Callbacks const&, rstudio::r::session::InternalCallbacks*) + 434
    frame #38: 0x0000000000d6791d rsession`rstudio::r::session::run(rstudio::r::session::ROptions const&, rstudio::r::session::RCallbacks const&) + 9581
    frame #39: 0x00000000006a7299 rsession`main + 10809
    frame #40: 0x00007f2b2530e830 libc.so.6`__libc_start_main(main=(rsession`main), argc=11, argv=0x00007ffcdab81fd8, init=<unavailable>, fini=<unavailable>, rtld_fini=<unavailable>, stack_end=0x00007ffcdab81fc8) + 240 at libc-start.c:291
    frame #41: 0x00000000006b4fe1 rsession`_start + 41
```

Which definitely looks like a memory problem on the Proteowizard side, that somehow just gets ignored in the base `R` process.

Comment: The output from `rstudioDiagnosticReport()` right after R crashes is available from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByilNUx_hjsqVlVheUcyRjR3RFk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm also sure that both versions of R are identical, as I have personally mapped my /usr/bin/R to a specific R installed from source.

Comment: Does mzR use Boost or BH? I have seen occasional interference wuth RStudio as it too uses Boost...

Comment: Yes, @DirkEddelbuettel is right, `mzR` uses Boost.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel mzR uses Boost in the proteowizard code that is used to read the mzML files, not sure about the mzXML files

Comment: @Laurent: With linking or just headers?  For 'just headers', I had two side-effects in anytime, but they do not affect core functionality. For 'linking' in my fork of KK's RcppMLPACK, I get immediate crashes.  In sum, I think you're fried and can do nuttin'.

Comment: That's odd. This all seemed to be fine in previous versions ....

Comment: FYI - I can't reproduce with `msdata_0.15.0`,  `mzR_2.9.1` and `Rcpp_0.12.8.3` using R devel and RStudio 0.99.903.

Comment: I think the one constant is the (apparently a littler older, embedded) Boost version in RStudio.  On our side, you could try different BH versions.

Comment: Tried installing mzR_2.9.3 from source (keeping all else the same), and that still has the same problem.

Comment: R-devel and devel versions of everything still crashes the RStudio daily.

Comment: New problem: R-devel compiled w/ options provided by Kevin Ushey below, won't compile Rcpp 0.12.9 w/ clang++-3.8 on Ubuntu 16.04. `undefined symbol: __ubsan_vptr_type_cache`. Thoughts @DirkEddelbuettel ??

Comment: You are missing ubsan libraries in the link step.

Comment: Also, please to use Twitter, let alone with my handle, if you want help. Come to the mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

When running this with a version of R compiled with sanitizers, I see:

```
> source("msdata.R", echo = TRUE)

> library(mzR)
Loading required package: Rcpp

> library(msdata)

> mzxml <- system.file("threonine/threonine_i2_e35_pH_tree.mzXML",
+                      package = "msdata")

> aa <- openMSfile(mzxml) # this works
ramp.cpp:1197:34: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'char [513]'
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: undefined-behavior ramp.cpp:1197:34 in

> mzml <- system.file("microtofq/MM8.mzML", package = "msdata")

> bb <- openMSfile(mzml) # this crashes R, but only in RStudio
```

In particular, this bit:

```
> aa <- openMSfile(mzxml) # this works
ramp.cpp:1197:34: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'char [513]'
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: undefined-behavior ramp.cpp:1197:34 in
```

implies there may be something going wrong with the `openMSfile()` function -- it appears to be attempting to read data at an invalid offset. I would file this issue with the [mzR](https://github.com/sneumann/mzR/issues/) maintainers.

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2017-01-17 r72002)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] msdata_0.15.0        mzR_2.9.3            Rcpp_0.12.9
[4] testthat_1.0.2       rmarkdown_1.3        knitr_1.15.1
[7] roxygen2_5.0.1       devtools_1.12.0.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_1.5        BiocGenerics_0.21.3 pkgload_0.0.0.9000
 [4] R6_2.2.0            stringr_1.1.0       tools_3.4.0
 [7] pkgbuild_0.0.0.9000 parallel_3.4.0      Biobase_2.35.0
[10] withr_1.0.2         htmltools_0.3.5     ProtGenerics_1.7.0
[13] rprojroot_1.2       digest_0.6.11       crayon_1.3.2
[16] codetools_0.2-15    memoise_1.0.0       evaluate_0.10
[19] stringi_1.1.2       compiler_3.4.0      backports_1.0.5
```

---

EDIT: Here's the configure call used to build R; the same compiler + flags are used for all built packages as well. (Extracted from `R.home("etc/Makeconf")`)

```
# R was configured using the following call
# (not including env. vars and site configuration)
# configure  '--with-blas=-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib -lopenblas' '--with-lapack=-L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib -llapack' '--with-cairo' '--disable-R-framework' '--enable-R-shlib' '--with-readline' '--enable-R-profiling' '--enable-memory-profiling' '--with-valgrind-instrumentation=2' '--without-internal-tzcode' '--prefix=/Users/kevin/r/r-devel-sanitizers' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig'

CC = clang-3.9 -std=gnu99 -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-sanitize=float-divide-by-zero
CXX = clang++-3.9 -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-sanitize=float-divide-by-zero
```

---

EDIT V2: Given the `lldb` stack trace, it looks like the culprit may indeed be a clash between Boost versions (the bundled version used by RStudio vs. the version used by `mzR`). Note that `mzR` is now inadvertently calling the Boost routines in the `rsession` executable, when it likely intends to call its own bundled version.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  So this, for once, does not seem to be a Boost issue.

Comment: Can someone specify the options used to compile R-devel? I'm trying to do a similar thing on my Ubuntu VM, and I'm not getting that same error, with the same versions. Thanks!

Used CC="gcc -std=gnu99 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer"